# MySQL replace based on something other than primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a row of records from a 3rd party, including a 3rd party id. Is there a way to use a `REPLACE` command, where it will use the 3rd party id instead of our internal one to know which records to overwrite if they already exist?

example data listing from 3rd party:

```
array( 'name' => 'Bob',
       'age' => '30',
       'external_ID' => '540745'
);
```

table structure for out database:

```
ID int auto_increment primary key, 
name varchar(255), 
age int,
external_id int
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `external_id` unique. AND it will work:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD UNIQUE(`external_id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I would refrain heavily from using REPLACE for a very big reason: [IT MECHANICALLY PERFORMS DELETE AND INSERT UNDER THE HOOD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) !!!**

[Here is a bug report from 2005-09-26](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13479) where MySQL would trip off an UPDATE trigger on REPLACE instead of DELETE and INSERT triggers. Even though this bug is fixed, if you have a version of MySQL prior to 2005-09-26, UPGRADE IMMEDIATELY or at least DON'T USE REPLACE !!!!

You are much better off using [INSERT IN DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead

[Percona blogs about this 4 months after the bug report was closed and recommends the new feature of **INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**.](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/18/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-replace-into/)

If you are just replacing the external_id, you may not need a UNIQUE INDEX on exteral_id.

Look what happens when you use REPLACE and a table with an auto_incrment ID:

REPLACE (internally DELETE and INSERT) would effectively change the id field associated with the external_id. If you tracked Bob, age 30, external ID 540745 with id 76 and id 76 is used in other tables to reference Bob, doing REPLACE may disconnect Bob from his original id that other tables may know him by.